# How to write the data back to Big Query using Databricks?

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, databricks, pyspark-pandas

I would like to upload my data frame to a Big query table using data bricks. I used the below code and got the following errors.

```
    bucket = "databricks-ci"
table = "custom-bidder.ciupdate.myTable"


df.write.format("bigquery").mode("overwrite").option("temporaryGcsBucket", bucket).option("table", table).save()
```

Error Message

[image]

I created a new bucket called "databricks-ci" and also created a dataset called "ciupdate" and just gave my table name here "myTable". My project is "custom-bidder"

I am not sure why it's not loading? Can anyone advise?

Comment: Can you copy paste the full error instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Could you share the complete Stack trace error to understand your issue? Make sure you have followed all the provided steps in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connect-databricks#before-you-begin) before you begin connecting Databricks to BigQuery.